# AppleScript Replace File

Tags: graphics, applescript, drivers

I'd like to write an AppleScript for replacing three system files with ones I've modified. I'd like to do this with an AppleScript instead of manually replacing them because I'll have to replace three files every time there's an OS X update. Specifically, I'll be replacing stock graphics drivers with ones I've modified to support a graphics card which is connected via Thunderbolt. Is it possible to write an AppleScript for replacing one file with another? I ask because I know that when you replace a file, a dialog pops up with three options, and I don't know how to address that.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with Finder:

```
set freshFile to choose file

tell application "Finder"
    move freshFile to desktop replacing yes
end tell
```

All you need to do is work out the source and destination paths to completely automate the script.

Many scripters do not like working with Finder, for a variety of reasons.  If you want something that is incredibly fast, you would use the **do shell script** inside of your AppleScript:

`do shell script " mv -f ~/Desktop/ArlandaTilUppsala.pdf ~/Documents/Employ.pdf"`

Comment: Oh, okay. Of course, I'm talking about replacing files in a subfolder with files from another location. But, would I just do something like this, including "replacing yes": set one to /J Drive/IONDRV/ | copy one to //System/Library/Extensions/IONDRVSupport.kext/  replace yes

Comment: Right, but in AppleScript, you would use colons instead of slashes, and quotations: `"Macintosh HD:Users:craigsmith:Desktop:Hello.pdf"`